# Where should I define operator >> for my specialization of std::pair?

Tags: c++, stl, template-specialization, argument-dependent-lookup

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std; //just for convenience, illustration only

typedef pair<int, int> point; //this is my specialization of pair. I call it point

istream& operator >> (istream & in, point & p)
{
    return in >> p.first >> p.second;
}

int main()
{
    vector<point> v((istream_iterator<point>(cin)), istream_iterator<point>()); 
    //             ^^^                         ^^^        
    //extra parentheses lest this should be mistaken for a function declaration
}
```

This fails to compile because as soon as ADL finds operator >> in namespace std it doesn't consider the global scope any more regardless of whether the operator found in std was a viable candidate or not. This is rather inconvenient. If I place the declaration of my operator >> into namespace std (which is technically illegal) the code compiles well as expected. Is there any way to resolve this issue other than make `point` my own class rather than typedefing it as a specialization of a template in std namespace?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You aren't specializing `std::pair` here.  I think this has more to do with the way templated code is parsed than with ADL itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding an overload of `operator>>` in `namespace std` is forbidden, but adding a template specialization is sometimes allowed.

However, there are no user-defined types here, and the operators on standard types are not yours to redefine.  Specializing `operator>>(istream&, pair<mytype, int>)` would be reasonable.

---

section `[namespace.std]` (section 17.6.4.2.1 of n3290) says

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified. **A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type** and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Does your answer imply that the answer to my question is ***no*** and I should make `point` a separate class?

Comment: Speaking for Ben Voigt, i'd say that yes, it does.

Comment: @Benoit: By the way, I don't understand that the operators on standard types are not mine to _re_define. There is no operator >> for pair, so I am not _re_defining anything, am I?

Comment: @Armen: Can you quote the paragraph from the standard that prohibits the library from providing `operator>>` for `pair`.

Comment: I can't find a quote that says you can't overload an operator on a standard library type.

Comment: @Ben: No, but I can assure you that the standard library doesn't say there must be an operator >> for pair

Comment: @Dennis: You can't add such an operator to namespace `std`, I added the relevant quote to my answer.

Comment: Right, but he isn't doing that.  Simply providing such an operator [not within namespace std] is perfectly kosher.  It just might not work properly, as he is witnessing.

Comment: @Dennis: Because of ADL, providing an operator outside namespace `std` is useless.  I was addressing the point raised in the question about "If I place the declaration of my `operator >>` into namespace `std` (which is technically illegal) the code compiles well as expected."