# operator << argument-dependent lookup does not look in global namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, argument-dependent-lookup

In the following scenario, inside function(), on line `ss << bb`, I get an error:

> binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'CommonType' (or there is no acceptable conversion) error.

My ADL understanding is that it will look into the current namespace (that is `AppNamespace::InnerNamespace`) and since no `operator <<` is found, it will look into the namespace of the arguments and as the `CommonType` is in global namespace I would expect that the `operator <<` defined in the CommonTypes.h to be found.
Obviously my understanding is wrong. Can anyone figure out how this should be working?

Main.cpp

```
namespace AppNamespace
{

    typedef std::vector<std::string> OtherType;

    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const OtherType& ot)
    {
        for (auto& el : ot)
        {
            os << el;
        }
        return os;
    }

    namespace InnerNamespace
    {
        void function()
        {
            CommonType bb;
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << bb;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    AppNamespace::InnerNamespace::function();
    return 0;
}
```

CommonTypes.h:

```
    #pragma once

#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<uint8_t> CommonType;

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const CommonType& bb)
{
        for (auto& el : bb)
        {
            os << el;
        }
        return os;
}
```

Comment: Even without the alias problem, your understanding of [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) is wrong. overloads of the namespace of argument are considered even is one exists at global namespace. We first build the set of namespace to consider.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that ADL lookup will be performed in `std` namespace and namespace where `CommonType` is declared is not relevant, so in order to make this work you need to place operator << in appropriate namespace:

```
namespace std
{

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const CommonType& bb)
{
    for (auto& el : bb)
    {
        os << el;
    }
    return os;
}

}
```

Comment: Isn't adding to namespace std UB? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: @PaulFloyd Not necessary, sometimes it is a proper way of utilizing standard library, for example `std::is_error_code_enum` or `std::default_delete` specializations.

Comment: that is mentioned in the link, partial specializations are allowed, declarations and full specializations not allowed.

Comment: @PaulFloyd That article is somewhat incomplete. `std::is_error_code_enum` is an example of allowed full specialization. In case of `operator <<` we can not place it anywhere else because ADL lookup will be performed in `std` namespace since both arguments are from `std` namespace. see [similar question - Where should I define operator >> for my specialization of std::pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885063/where-should-i-define-operator-for-my-specialization-of-stdpair)

Comment: "Isn't adding to namespace std UB?" - Usually, yes. But the standard explicitly allows adding template specializations to namespace std (and, as far as I know, that's the only thing you are allowed to add).

Answer (score 1):

> My ADL understanding is that it will look into the current namespace (that is `AppNamespace::InnerNamespace`) and since no << operator is found, it will look into the `namespace` of the arguments and as the `CommonType` is in global namespace I would expect that the << operator defined in the CommonTypes.h to be found.

The misunderstanding is that `CommonType` is a new type. It is not a new type. It is just an alias.

You can resolve the function lookup problem using various methods.

1. Define both the `operator<<` functions in the global namespace.

   ```
   #include <string>
   #include <sstream>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <cstdint>

   // Put everything from CommonTypes.h here to simplify things.
   typedef std::vector<uint8_t> CommonType;

   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, CommonType const& bb)
   {
      for (auto& el : bb)
      {
         os << el;
      }
      return os;
   }

   namespace AppNamespace
   {
       typedef std::vector<std::string> OtherType;
   }

   std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const AppNamespace::OtherType& ot)
   {
      for (auto& el : ot)
      {
         os << el;
      }
      return os;
   }

   namespace AppNamespace
   {
      namespace InnerNamespace
      {
         void function()
         {
            CommonType bb;
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << bb;
         }
      }
   }


   int main()
   {
      AppNamespace::InnerNamespace::function();
      return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Define both the `operator<<` functions in `AppNamespace` namespace.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <cstdint>

   // Put everything from CommonTypes.h here to simplify things.
   typedef std::vector<uint8_t> CommonType;

   namespace AppNamespace
   {
      std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, CommonType const& bb)
      {
         for (auto& el : bb)
         {
            os << el;
         }
         return os;
      }

      typedef std::vector<std::string> OtherType;
      std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const OtherType& ot)
      {
         for (auto& el : ot)
         {
            os << el;
         }
         return os;
      }

      namespace InnerNamespace
      {
         void function()
         {
            CommonType bb;
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << bb;
         }
      }
   }


   int main()
   {
      AppNamespace::InnerNamespace::function();
      return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Define `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, CommonType const& bb)` in another namespace and explicitly bring that function into scope in `AppNamespace`.

   ```
   #include <string>
   #include <sstream>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <cstdint>

   // Put everything from CommonTypes.h here to simplify things.
   typedef std::vector<uint8_t> CommonType;

   namespace CommonNamespace
   {
      std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, CommonType const& bb)
      {
         for (auto& el : bb)
         {
            os << el;
         }
         return os;
      }
   }

   namespace AppNamespace
   {
      // Bring the operator<< functions in CommonNamespace into the scope of
      // this namespace.
      using CommonNamespace::operator<<;

      typedef std::vector<std::string> OtherType;
      std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const OtherType& ot)
      {
         for (auto& el : ot)
         {
            os << el;
         }
         return os;
      }

      namespace InnerNamespace
      {
         void function()
         {
            CommonType bb;
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << bb;
         }
      }
   }


   int main()
   {
      AppNamespace::InnerNamespace::function();
      return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the three solutions!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to move your operator in `std` namespace as recommended by VTT, you can specify that it lives in the global namespace:

```
(::operator <<)(ss, bb);
```